# enterprise architect bad characters encoding

Tags: character-encoding, enterprise-architect

I am using EA 12.0 Corporate edition Built 1215 - Unicode with database version 4.01 and I have the following problem.
When I type one of theses characters: "ě č ř" and then save and reopen diagram the characters are replaced by e c r. Same thing happens if I just copy element with these characters (shown on example image bellow).

Here are more information:

- Doesn't matter where are the characters typed. It could be at notes, properties, model, package, diagram, element... just anywhere
- It happens when diagram is reopened or the element is just copied.
- Doesn't matter if it is new project or existing
- I tried different versions of EA (11, 12.1, 13) and it also has no effect
- Doesn't matter if using "JET 4.0" (Options > general > "Use JET 4.0 - requires restart")

I have to use EA, so workaround using different program will not help.

Thank you for any information, any help is appreciated.

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OoCz.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think you not only have to turn the flag **Use Jet 4.0** on, but you also need a 4.0 startermodel.
Now you are probably using the right driver on the wrong (v3.5) database.
IIRC you can download one from the Sparx website.

Comment: See also http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/12.0/projects_and_teams/generalsettings.html chapter "Use Jet 4.0 - requires restart"

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and all you have to do is to change your non-Unicode language Windows preference to your local.

Comment: This worked for me (english windows, document in local language)